# Glide does not resolve its method

Tags: android, android-glide

Today I'm trying to use `Glide` image loader in my android application while using this I had facing method not resolving problem.

```
Glide
     .with(this)
     .load(R.drawable.image_default_profile_picture)
     .into(mUserImage);
```

This code working pretty fine. But when I'm trying this

```
Glide
     .with(this)
     .load(R.drawable.image_default_profile_picture)
     .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
     .fitCenter()
     .into(mUserImage);
```

Then this saying cannot resolve method `fitCenter()`, `placeholder`.
What I am missing?

Comment: Which glide version are you using?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Seems like updated library has any issue. Add **`.apply(new RequestOptions()`** to continue with latest version.

**CODE**

```
Glide
 .with(this)
 .load(R.drawable.image_default_profile_picture)
 .apply(new RequestOptions()
 .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
 .fitCenter())
 .into(mUserImage);
```

Comment: That worked for me, thanks! One side note, you can leave the 'annotationProcessor` as is (4.0.0-RC0).

Comment: Ive already done this.But cannot resolve issues.ver `3.5.2` won't let me use asGIf() method.

Comment: this is not the solution to downgrade version, please go with @James Jordan Taylor's answer.

Comment: Sameer Bhat tried to edit the post with this comment: "you missed a closing round bracket, thanks btw" I'm not sure if they proposed a correct change, but please review your syntax

Comment: `Glide.with(context*).using(FirebaseImageLoader()).load(storageReference).into(holder.image)`. `using` method not found. Can you help on this.

Answer (score 47):

You can still use `.placeholder()` with the latest version of Glide, you just have to add it as an applied `RequestOption` in the method chain, i.e.

```
Glide.with(this)
     .load(floorplanUrl)
     .apply(new RequestOptions()
           .placeholder(R.drawable.floorplan_unavailable))
     .into(floorplanImageView);
```

Comment: this should be accepted answer instead of giving an answer to downgrade the glide version.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!  I just upgraded old code and some references threw an error.  I see this is needed now when using Default Glide rather than the Customizable Fluid Interface in which case we need to reference GlideApp instead.  I got the Customizable Image Loading on Android by Peitek and Pohls book for more explanations and examples.

Answer (score 38):

If you use Glide package dependences  `compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'` than use below code

```
Glide
    .with(your_context)
    .load(image_url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.image_loading)
    .error(R.drawable.image_error)
    .into(imageView);
```

> **Note:** As in [doc](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)
>   **Round Pictures**: CircleImageView/CircularImageView/RoundedImageView are
>   known to have issues with TransitionDrawable (.crossFade() with
>   .thumbnail() or .placeholder()) and animated GIFs, use a
>   BitmapTransformation (.circleCrop() will be available in v4) or
>   .dontAnimate() to fix the issue.

Latest update version `compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1'` or above than use below code

```
Glide.with(your_context)
     .load(url)
     .apply(new RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_loading_image)
                .centerCrop()
                .dontAnimate()
                .dontTransform())
                .into(imageView);
```

---

If you want to **load `GIF File` in to `Glide`** with using `compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'` than use **`.asGif()`** method after **`.load()`**

```
Glide
    .with(your_context)
    .load(image_url)
    .asGif()
    .into(imageView);
```

If you use `compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1'` or higher(latest) dependences than,

```
Glide
    .with(your_context)
    .asGif()
    .load(image_url)
    .into(imageView);
```

> **Note:** If  you are useing `glide:glide:4.1.1` or higher version than not necessary to use **.asGif()** method to load `GIF` file it will
>   load `GIF File` automatically
>
> See Latest version of **[glide, Bug fixes, Features](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/releases)**

Comment: compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1' or greater version did trick to me. Thank you.

Comment: you are  wc @IPKaal

Answer (score 16):

For using `fitCenter()` and other scale type changes with the Glide version starting from v4.0, you need include special class in your app.

```
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;

@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
}
```

After that rebuild  the project, and you can start using Glide on that manner

```
GlideApp.with(imageView)
    .load("...")
    .fitCenter()
    .into(imageView);
```

[Documentation](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html)

Answer (score 4):

Glide version: `4.8.0`

```
Glide.with(this)
        .load("https://media.giphy.com/media/98uBZTzlXMhkk/giphy.gif")
        .apply(new RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.error)
                .centerCrop()
                .fitCenter())
        .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use the newest library `'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'`, [The official Github page](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) suggests the following:

> Round Pictures: CircleImageView/CircularImageView/RoundedImageView are
>   known to have issues with TransitionDrawable (**.crossFade()** with
>   .thumbnail() or .placeholder()) and animated GIFs, use a
>   BitmapTransformation (**.circleCrop()** will be available in v4) or
>   **.dontAnimate()** to fix the issue.

Otherwise use the following library version:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Answer (score -2):

compile this library:-

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```