# Why Glide is not loading https images in android?

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I am trying to load https images in imageview using Glide. The image is not loading, but if I provide some local image (ex. R.drawable.error_image), it loads.

imagePath = "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/d3/6b/83/d36b83e986e500aa7f39c722970f1f97.jpg"; // Sample image took from internet

```
Glide.with(this)
      .load(imagePath)
      .into(landingImage);
```

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
```

I tried to search in SOF also but did't get fix. Give suggestions thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try to debug?

And what does it mean "if I provide some error image that will load"? if you use local images, or ...? different URLs?

Comment: @Markon Thanks for ur valuable time. Error image means - Image from drawable in my project

Answer (score 2):

Try downgrading to some previous version ex.

`compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'`

Have a look at this answer:
[Glide does not resolve its method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44198856/glide-does-not-resolve-its-method/44199289#44199289)

Answer (score 1):

> yes it is not working, same Problem i have found in Picasso and glide
>   also but i have solved it by using below link.

[Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: Feel free to provide evidence for your claim. As a counter-example, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/HTTP/Picasso) loads HTTPS images just fine (Picasso, not Glide).

Answer (score 0):

It works for me by using dependancy Android-Universal-Image-Loader

```
implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
```

load image

```
private DisplayImageOptions options;
private void LoadImage(String image_url) {

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getActivity()));

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
            .build();


    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    //mImageViewOne : image view 
    imageLoader.displayImage(image_url,mImageViewOne,options);
}
```