# Glide cannot resolve method .asGif()

Tags: android, android-glide

I have the code:

```
  Glide.with(getActivity())
  .load(myurl)
  .asGif()
  .into(ivGif);
```

and I imported glide in gradle:

```
  repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
  }

dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'
}
```

Compiler says

> cannot resolve method .asGif()

Do I miss something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44198856/glide-does-not-resolve-its-method

Comment: @AmitVaghela does v3.5.2 support gif? I prefer to use last version for any lib

Comment: both will support gif

Comment: @AmitVaghela yeah that solved the problem but it's not what I expected

Comment: where have you stuck ?

Comment: @AmitVaghela v3.5.2 works good for my scenario but I preferr to use latest version v4.2

Comment: should i post a answer???

Answer (score 5):

On older versions of Glide you can use like this:

```
GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView, LOOP_COUNT);
Glide.with(mContext)
    .load(yourgif)
    .into(imageViewTarget);
```

As of Glide version 4.x, `asGif()` method is removed. You can handle gif just like this:

```
Glide.with(mContext)
    .load(yourgif)
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: please gife code for GlideDrawableImageViewTarget class

Comment: @Dika My answer is a bit outdated. After Glide upgrades v4, this class has been removed. You can check this answer to find an alternative to GlideDrawableImageTarget. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51531284/3669559

Comment: @Dika I was thinking about updating my answer when I am available but you changed my answer entirely. I made my answer more comprehensive. Still some people use older versions of Glide library.

Comment: Thanks @OğuzhanDöngül this should be the accepted answer.