# GlideDrawableImageViewTarget not found in Glide-4

Tags: android, android-glide

Why `GlideDrawableImageViewTarget` is not found in Glide4+? What is the alternative?

**My code:**

```
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.GlideDrawableImageViewTarget;


Glide.with(getContext())
                    .load(R.drawable.loader_gif_image)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .into(new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView));
        }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE**

> Use below code if you are using **`glide:4.9.0`**

```
    Glide.with(this)
            .load("")
            .apply(new RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
            .into(new DrawableImageViewTarget(imageView));


    // or use this

    Glide.with(this)
            .load("")
            .apply(new RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
            .into(new CustomTarget<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(resource);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                }
            });
```

Try this

> You can use [**`new SimpleTarget<Drawable>()`**](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/targets.html)

```
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.ic_favorite)
            .apply(new RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(resource);
                }
            });
```

Try this

> You can use [**`new Target<Drawable>()`**](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/targets.html)

```
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.ic_favorite)
            .apply(new RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
            .into(new Target<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadStarted(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadFailed(@Nullable Drawable errorDrawable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(resource);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                }

                @Override
                public void getSize(@NonNull SizeReadyCallback cb) {

                }

                @Override
                public void removeCallback(@NonNull SizeReadyCallback cb) {

                }

                @Override
                public void setRequest(@Nullable Request request) {

                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public Request getRequest() {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void onStart() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStop() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onDestroy() {

                }
            });
```

Comment: May i know the reason for a downvote so i can improve my answer

Comment: @AnuPramod i don't know why its downvoted did my answer help you

Comment: Yes.. It helped

Comment: @Alston sorry to hear that please check updated answer, for `Glide:4.9.0` you need to use `CustomTarget<Drawable>()` instead of `SimpleTarget<Drawable>()`

Answer (score 8):

Update your `dependency`  in `build.gradle` to `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'`

Try to import `DrawableImageViewTarget` instead of `GlideDrawableImageViewTarget`

Or Use code as below.

```
Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark).apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)).into(new DrawableImageViewTarget(holder.profileImage));
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

`new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>()` is deprecated. You can use
 `new CustomTarget<Bitmap>()`.

````
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                super.onLoadFailed(placeholder);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadFailed(@Nullable Drawable errorDrawable) {
                super.onLoadFailed(errorDrawable);
            }
        };```
````

Answer (score 0):

`GlideDrawable` are **deprecated**, use simple Drawable

```
            Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(item.getFriendUserPhotoUrl())
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {

                        fullname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile_default_photo);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {

                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        fullname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(holder.thumbnail);
```