# After updating dependencies from Glide 3.7 to Glide 4.9.0, error saying "cannot resolve symbol Glide "

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-glide

I was previously using Glide 3.7.0 . Now I've changed the line in Gradle from

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
```

After that I synced the Gradle and Rebuilt my project but getting error in building as below-

> error: cannot find symbol class GlideDrawableImageViewTarget

IN MY CODE IN WHICH I'M GETTING ERROR, I IMPORTED GLIDE LIKE THIS-

```
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.GlideDrawableImageViewTarget;

I implemented the Glide in the same file as below -
public void showCustomDialog(Activity context) {
        dialogView = new Dialog(context);
        dialogView.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialogView.setContentView(R.layout.layout_progress_dialog);

        iv1 = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.iv1);
        GlideDrawableImageViewTarget ivSmily = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(iv1);
        Glide.with(context).load(R.raw.loader).into(ivSmily);

        dialogView.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialogView.show();
    }
```

I think I need to updated these implementation codes in Glide V4, but don't have any idea what codes should I use for Glide V4.

Comment: Refer this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51531229/glidedrawableimageviewtarget-not-found-in-glide-4

Comment: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53520004/2289835) can be used.